# Webpack 1.12: Bundle css files

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm successfully bundling .js files and processing them correctly with the loaders. My current config is here:

```
"use strict";

var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: 'main.js',
        vendor: ["fixed-data-table","react","react-dom","jquery", "bootstrap"],
    },
    output: { path: "../resources/public", filename: 'bundle.js' },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"static/vendor.bundle.js"),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

I now have a bunch of css files, some of them from the vendor modules as well. How do I bundle them in the same manner to a bundle.css for my own(there's just one) and vendor.bundle.css for the modules, similar to the structure above?

Comment: extract text plugin can help here

Comment: OK. I found this: https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#using-css , i will try to use their documentation(it's a bit of a mess though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the extract-text-webpack-plugin is exactly what you want for achieving this. More info [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin). I use it on all my webpack builds and rather simple to implement. You will also need to use style-loader/css-loader along with the extract text plugin. Once you do all that your webpack config should look something like this.
    var webpack = require("webpack");

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
        main: 'main.js',
        vendor: ["fixed-data-table","react","react-dom","jquery", "bootstrap"],
    },
    output: { path: "../resources/public", filename: 'bundle.js' },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"static/vendor.bundle.js"),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
              test: /.js?$/,
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
              }
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader","css-loader"),
            },
        ]
    },
};
```

From there just require your css file within your main.js file.

```
require('./path/to/style.css');
```

Now when you run webpack it should output a css file within your root directory.

Comment: In newer versions, it takes only one object as parameter: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader"})

Comment: Note that the extract-text-webpack-plugin is deprecated (https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin) and should not be used. Instead of, you can use mini-css-extract-plugin (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin).