# Flat @import [url] css resources into the called css file

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I have the following CSS file with @imports

```
// main.css
@import url("theme/default.css");
@import url("theme/print.css");
```

default.css

```
a {
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

I am looking for a way to flat all the resource into the main.css file.

example:

```
// main.css
// output from theme/default.css
a {
  font-size: 12px;
}...
```

Thanks, Michael

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achive. Doesn't `import` do exactly this?

Comment: create css file and put there all your imports then import only the css you created

Comment: ur question are not clear. Are you using Webpack (I ask because the tag used on ur question)?

Comment: you mean "a" selector following all imported css file?

Comment: @Elizeu I think it can be done by webpack but I am not sure.

Comment: If you are using Webpack, you need bundle your files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086079/webpack-1-12-bundle-css-files
If not using webpack, remove the tag webpack and use bundle.

Comment: https://medium.com/trabe/multiple-css-bundles-with-webpack-75f263095f09